# Why doesn’t the verb “read” have a corresponding noun form suffixed with “‑tion/‑ion/‑sion”?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, suffixes, derivational-morphology, is-it-a-rule

Why there isn’t a *‑tion/‑ion/‑sion* derived form for the verb *read* verb,
such as for example the non-existent ✼*readation* or ✼*readition*?

Example with an *‑tion* form:

- exsanguination
- disobstruction
- remancipation
- overoxygenation
- extrinsication

Examples with *‑ion*:

- annotation
- conjugation
- insertion
- direction

Examples with *‑isation*:

- extremisation
- molarisation
- ovalisation
- metroisation

Comment: What about "run", "eat", "see", "walk"??

Comment: Is there an explanation of such behaviour?

Comment: Well, I looked upon wiktionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tion
Couldn't find any explanation so I came up here

Comment: 'Reading' has achieved full deverbal status. _There were two readings in the morning service. / Different readings are of course possible_. And the non-count ing-form usage is very common: _Her reading is really coming along._ We _do_ fall back on 'reading material', admittedly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, I see, found reading about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Note that one shouldn't say " 'reading' is a deverbal noun." In usages such as 'These meter readings are very high', the plural usage shows deverbalisation. With 'Brown's patiently reading to his little daughter was a joy to behold', consult Quirk et al for where 'reading' is on the verbo-nominal scale.

Comment: I recall that several times as a schoolboy, I won money from my peers by betting I could teach them a thousand French words in less than 60 seconds. Once I saw the colour of their money, I'd just tell them that ***all English words ending in -TION also exist in French.*** That's because they all derive from LATIN, whereas ***to read*** doesn't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your schoolboy trick sure took a lot of **gumption**. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I don't recall anyone throwing *that* one back in my face! In fact, I doubt I ever heard the word ***gumption*** from anyone except my grandmother when I was a kid. But I ***do*** remember some of my smartass schoolboy chums complaining that English ***station*** is French ***gare***. I've forgotten now how ***station*** is used in French, but I definitely recall looking it up in Harraps to prove that the word did exist, even if it didn't mean exactly the same thing!

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's used for almost all the same things in French as it is in English, there is even the term "station de chemin de fer" which a long winded way of saying "gare". All the other uses like "research station", "action stations" and "station in life" are almost  exact translations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Simple Explanation

The easy answer is because *read* is a **Germanic** verb, whereas all those others come from **Latin** verbs — and indeed often enough from actual Latin nouns like English *conjugation* < [Latin *conjugatio*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conjugatio#Latin).

Latin never had a **readatio* noun, and thus neither does English. It did, however, have [*lectiones*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lectio#Latin) that were read by [*lectors*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lector#Latin). The word *lection* does exist in English, but it is by no means common, especially today. Few would understand you outside certain ecclesiastical circles. From the OED:

> - 1885   W. Pater *Marius the Epicurean* II. 135   
>   Those lections, or sacred readings, which..occurred at certain intervals amid the silence of the assembly.
> - 1927   Alan Hugh McNeile *An introduction to the study of the New Testament* 383  
>    It [*sc*. the Codex Bezae] contains certain lection marks which Brightman holds to be Byzantine.

---

## Technical Explanation

In their professional linguistics paper on [“Restricting suffix combinations in English and German”](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://linguistics.stonybrook.edu/people/_bios/_linguistics-faculty/_faculty-files/aronoff/Restricting%2520suffix%2520combinations%2520in%2520English%2520and%2520German.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm3ngp1okQaqNtkvFby4rdNnkr_jKg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr) from pp. 451–490 of the journal *Natural Language & Linguistic Theory,* Vol. 20, № 3 (August 2002), authors Mark Aronoff and Nanna Fuhrhop write:

> Although English morphology has a highly productive Latinate component, the fact that
> only the Germanic suffixes obey the monosuffix constraint shows that the
> two types of suffixes are still distinct.  Furthermore, although Latinate
> suffixes may disobey the constraint, they attach to unsuffixed words much
> less commonly than Germanic suffixes do, and they normally attach to
> suffixes which also carry the feature Latinate, so the picture drawn here
> is that there are two different word-formation systems, especially within
> the combination of suffixes, one Germanic and one Latinate. Latinate
> suffixes do not attach frequently to free monomorphemic stems, while
> Germanic suffixes, for the most part, do (this is the monosuffix
> constraint). Latinate suffixes attach frequently to free polymorphemic
> stems, while Germanic suffixes (except *‑ness*) do not.  So, the two types
> of suffixes are largely in complementary distribution.

The major takeaways from that paragraph that apply to your question are:

1. English has two distinct word-formation systems.
2. Latinate suffixes seldom attach to free monomorphemic stems...
3. ... least of all to ones that themselves lack the Latinate property.

Your verb *read* is a a free monomorphemic stem which furthermore lacks the trait of being Latinate, while your various *‑tion/‑sion/-cion* type suffixes are Latinate ones.

Hence the constraint against that combination.

Comment: Nice observation. Yes. Latinate words had the "io" form right back to when Latin was spoken as a living language. English had the  "ing" form all the way back to Old English which was a West Germanic language.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Updated to include technical explanation from a peer-reviewed professional journal.